# How to call if a property member is of a function type , dynamically in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

**I want to call if the member is a function. How to do that in typesript.**

**Does typescript discourage dynamic typing ?**

```
function call_IF_Fucntion<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, propName: K) {

  if (typeof obj[propName] === "function") {
     
      obj[propName]();

     //// This expression is not callable, Type unknown ha no call signature
     
  }

}


let x = {
  name: "manas",
  age: 30,
  run: () => {
    console.log("running ... ");
  }
};

call_IF_Fucntion(x, "run");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly what's happening here is that TypeScript does not use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the type of a property if the index is performed using bracket notation (like `obj[propName]`) instead of using dot notation (like `obj.xyz`).  This is considered a bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530), and it hasn't been fixed because the fix slowed down the compiler too much, and because it's not clear how to do this safely in all situations (See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41612#issuecomment-731351014) on a related issue for more information).

The workaround that one generally uses here is to save the property into its own variable, and then use control flow analysis to narrow that variable:

```
function call_IF_Fucntion<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, propName: K) {
  const objPropName = obj[propName];
  if (typeof objPropName === "function") {
    // const objPropName: T[K] & Function
    objPropName(); // okay
  }
}
```

See how `objPropName` is narrowed from `T[K]` to `T[K] & Function`, and is thus considered callable.

---

Do note that this is not really type safe; the type `Function` is like `(...args: any) => any` and it says you can call the function with any arguments or no arguments.  But some functions rely on particular argument types:

```
call_IF_Fucntion({ oops: (s: string) => s.toUpperCase() }, "oops");
// apparently okay, but runtime error, s is undefined
```

If you want to prevent this, you should [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` so that its function-valued properties really don't require any arguments... maybe like this:

```
function call_IF_Function<
  T extends Record<K, (() => void) | string | number>,
  K extends keyof T
>(obj: T, propName: K) {
  const objPropName = obj[propName];
  if (typeof objPropName === "function") {
    // const objPropName: T[K] & Function
    objPropName();
  }
}
```

And now you will get safer behavior:

```
call_IF_Function(x, "name"); // okay

call_IF_Function({ oops: (s: string) => s.toUpperCase() }, "oops"); // error!
// --------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '(s: string) => string' is not assignable to type '() => void'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQfQJIDFO4gRiwIA8AKgDSIDSiApgB5QNgAmAzogNYMCecYIgoA+ABRwARgCsAXCJoAHAE5wlAORQBbBgtoBKRAG8AUImQJOURNJkAFNZp0NEAXluyA2qvVbdALoA3OaIMMLiUPxKDEKeDk7+rm4piABEoJCkYGlGZhYWAPSFlmDW8Y5+LgoUXrQBiABkiIRZ8GChFnaVzrriBiEWAL6mI6ZoDDZM7iahYNXp2ijznGlUoSgA5nqIAMwADOsWKuAK-e6iswWlnHATAHRocJviaSdgYDBgm4j3f+kDUIjIYhUyoDA4fCEYjZcRMGhpea6XKg8FYPAEIgkdriYy2dScM6ExDWFRfTZGNyXTj3KBwACqShiKgAwihOAxzkMEXACSjTMVECgmSgVGwoGh+LYeCh+DQpCAbO9YLpGCo1CoaNwYNxwOwGMAvgx2KZTZloO1kOh0VDwBbyKEKIwWGwuIgAEoMCBwFTsMi0Gjic5UxAANzgMHYRgAPiSoGTvohY2AQNopAwVKIjnRnawONw+IJhBRTBI7DVlIkFoYrjcbN0q6qPHYfI2GMFQuFEJForFhA2qk3Uhk7dlcrWiiVvWV67IekkanUGs1WvaOtcB71OYDhqNTWjIZi2gg4QikQx+WDrYfV7C8bylMTxMTSeTKdTaQymRm2RyuTy+QGRBBQzDUAEIBRKABaGDYLg+D4MuAA-FDULQ9CMMwlDIJEXtEAAcmfBRX2+d84wTTZ8LCbgwDgGx2U4GBNnmKQJkQOl2LwwiyPDSN8NMIA)

Comment: Thanks for giving time and writing a detailed answer. Highly appreciated 